# Pascal - Sum of odd numbers between 0 and X

Tags: pascal

**I've beeng having some trouble with this code... I need to create an algorithm which makes the user input a number (X), and then the program calculates the sum of all the odd numbers below (x).**

This what I've tried so far, but can't really wrap my head around the logic behind it:

```
Program odd_numbers;
Var
  Num, Limite, Soma: integer;
Begin;
 Soma := 0;
 Writeln('Choose a limit:');
 Readln(Limite);    
        While (Limite / 2 > 0) do
            Begin;
                Soma := ((Num < Limite) mod 2 > 0);                                 
                Writeln('The sum of odd numbers from 0 to ', Limite, ' é ', Soma);
            End;

        if (Limite mod 2 = 0) then
            Begin;
                Soma := ((Num < Limite) mod 2 = 0);
                Writeln('The sum of odd numbers from 0 to ', Limite, ' é ', Soma);
            End;
End.
```

*PS: Been writing the code with variables in Portuguese, so don't mind the variables appearing weird to understand. *

Comment: What, specifically, is your problem here? Is your code not working as you expect? Are you getting errors when you compile, or errors when you run? If you are getting errors, what are the error messages? You need to provide much more information before anyone can provide useful assistance.

Comment: What happens if you step through it ?

Comment: You know you can calculate this number without a loop, right? Just take a look at [arithmetic sequences](http://www.mathwords.com/a/arithmetic_sequence.htm). Much easier, much faster.

Comment: Indeed, you should NOT use a loop here. Simply apply the formula for an arithmetic sum, as Rudy suggests.

Comment: "Been writing the code with variables in Portuguese". It would have been good manners to translate them into English before posting the Q at SO.

Answer (score 1):

I  see that everyone is happily looping, but this is not necessary. This is a simple arithmetic sequence, and the sum can be calculated without a loop.

Just think of the following:

```
1 + 3                  = 2 * (1 +  3) / 2 = 2 * 2 = 4   ; limits 3 and 4
1 + 3 + 5              = 3 * (1 +  5) / 2 = 3 * 3 = 9   ; limits 5 and 6
1 + 3 + 5 + 7          = 4 * (1 +  7) / 2 = 4 * 4 = 16  ; limits 7 and 8
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9      = 5 * (1 +  9) / 2 = 5 * 5 = 25  ; limits 9 and 10
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 = 6 * (1 + 11) / 2 = 6 * 6 = 36  ; limits 11 and 12
```

But not only that, you'll see that it is in fact always a perfect square: `Sqr((n+1) div 2)`.

So just calculate:

```
program odd_numbers;
var
  Num, Limite, Soma: Integer;
begin
  Write('Choose a limit: ');
  Readln(Limite);
  Num := (Limite + 1) div 2;
  Soma := Num * Num;
  Writeln('The sum of odd numbers from 0 to ', Limite, ' is ', Soma);
end.
```

Looks a little simpler than what the others propose.

Comment: Congrats and +1, I thought about the same during a trip to the grocery, and in the meantime you already posted it. One minor detail though: the task was *...sum of all odd numbers below (X)*, iow less than x. The easy fix is to remove `+1` from your formula. That will also make it work for negative values.

Comment: Yes, I *read* below, but I was not sure that that was meant. Often if people say *below* they mean *upto and including*. Especially the part `'The sum of odd numbers from 0 to ', Limite, ' é ', Soma` made me think the latter was meant (0 upto an including Limite).

Answer (score 0):

The loop `While (Limite / 2 > 0) do ...` uses real arithmetic and not integer arithmetic. I guess you mean `While (Limite div 2 > 0) do ...` And you should change `Limite` in the loop otherwise you get stuck because the exit condition can never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

After you have asked the user to enter a number, `Limite`, you need to keep that unchanged, because you need it in the final message. You also need a loop where you go through all numbers from `Limite` towards 0.

You started with a `while` loop which is ok, you are just missing the *loop control variable*. That is a variable that eventually gets a terminating value which then stops the loop. Use for example the `Num` variable you already have declared. You can use the same variable to investigate the numbers between user input and 0, for being odd values.

```
num := limite-1; // give num a start value based on user input (-1 because of "... numbers below (x)")
while num > 0 do // stop the loop when 0 is reached
begin
  // here you investigate if `num` is a odd number (e.g. using `mod` operator or
  // possibly your pascal has a built in `function Odd(value: integer): boolean;`)
  // and add it to `Soma` if it is
  num := num - 1;// decrement num at every iteration
end;
```

Finally you need to consider changes to the above, to handle negative input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

To test if an integer is an odd value, you could use following function:

```
function IsOdd( value : Integer) : Boolean;
begin
  IsOdd := (value mod 2) <> 0;
end;
```

Many pascal compilers have a built-in function called `Odd()`, which you could use.

A while loop works well to solve this problem. If you start with lowest odd number above zero, i.e. one and continue upwards so long we do not exceed the limit value we have a simple start:

```
function GetOddSumBelowX( X : Integer) : Integer;
var
  i,sum: Integer;
begin
  i := 1;  // Start with first odd number
  sum := 0;
  while (i < X) do begin // as long as i less than X, loop
    if IsOdd(i) then begin
      sum := sum + i; // add to sum
    end;
    i := i + 1;  // Increment i 
  end;
  GetOddSumBelowX := sum;
end;
```

Now, that was simple enough. Next step to simplify the loop is to increment the i variable by two instead, just to jump between all odd numbers:

```
function GetOddSumBelowX( X : Integer) : Integer;
var
  i,sum: Integer;
begin
  i := 1;  // Start with first odd number
  sum := 0;
  while (i < X) do begin // as long as i less than X, loop
    sum := sum + i; // add to sum
    i := i + 2;  // Increment to next odd number
  end;
  GetOddSumBelowX := sum;
end;
```